# How do i modify the vba code to reply with attachments via outlook and include png(in email signature)?

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

How do i modify the vba code to reply with attachments and include png(in email signature)?

```
Sub AnyUpdatesForOS()

Dim OrgEmail As MailItem
Dim ReEmail As MailItem

Set OrgEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
Set ReEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Deski\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\AnyUpdatesForOS.oft")

ReEmail.To = OrgEmail.Sender
ReEmail.CC = OrgEmail.CC
ReEmail.BCC = OrgEmail.BCC
ReEmail.Subject = OrgEmail.Subject

ReEmail.HTMLBody = ReEmail.HTMLBody & OrgEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
ReEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add new text, the appropriate (reply) signature, and the original email text to the reply?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) method instead. To add additional attachments you can use the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method.

```
Sub AnyUpdatesForOS()

Dim OrgEmail As MailItem
Dim ReEmail As MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Attachments

Set OrgEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
Set ReEmail = OrgEmail.Forward()

Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", olByValue, 1, "Test" 

ReEmail.Display

End Sub
```